# How do I disable the Symfony 2 profiler bar?

Tags: debugging, symfony, profiler

It's not adding anything and it makes the page slower and I want it gone. Don't ask. There's little about the profiler on the website and nothing in the app config.

Comment: It appears only in dev and there is sooo much, that makes the page slower (in dev env): I think it isn't worth it ;)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

This setting is in `app/config/config_dev.yml`:

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false
```

Comment: As a comment for future developers. This answer is the best if you want to "DISABLE" REDIRECTS in dev mode and be able to debug POST and so on. Just intercept_redirects: true and it will work :D

Answer (score 90):

Additional: if you want to disable it for a special action in your controller than use this:

```
if ($this->container->has('profiler'))
{
    $this->container->get('profiler')->disable();
}
```

Comment: This was what I was actually searching for. Need to disble the toolbar when generating and displaying a pdf. the toolbar looks rather silly in a pdf :)

Comment: To still get output in /_profiler but without the toolbar, you can cheat: `$request->headers->add(array('X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'));` That's because in WebProfilerBundle/EventListener/WebDebugToolbarListener.php there's an explicit check for this before injecting the toolbar.

Comment: @Besnik, can you please also include the solution for SF3 and SF4. It's on this link 
https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/profiler/m

I could do it myself but as your answer is best referenced I think this is more useful here.

Answer (score 19):

If you set `framework.profiler.collect` to `false` in your config.yml, the profiler bar won't be shown (even if `web_profiler.toolbar` is set to true).

```
 framework:
    profiler:
        collect: false
```

This then allows you to selectively activate collectors in your code manually, like this:

```
$this->container->get('profiler')->enable();
```

Documentation here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#collect

Comment: (This is the opposite of the equally valid approach taken in @besnik's answer.)

Answer (score 6):

If you have created a new Symfony project since Symfony 2.5, these parameters are set in `app/config/paramaters.yml`

```
parameters:
    # ...
    debug_toolbar: true
    debug_redirects: false
```

Just set `debug_toolbar` to `false`.

Answer (score 6):

**Symfony 5.3.7**

I changed the toolbar value to false in the web_profiler.yaml and the toolbar was disabled.

```
{# [root_directory]/config/packages/dev/web_profiler.yaml #}

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true  --> Change to false
    intercept_redirects: false
```

Comment: This seems to be the working way nowadays, as most answers are from years ago.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
framework:
    profiler: { only_exceptions: true }
```

in your `app/config/config_dev.yml`

Answer (score 3):

To still get output in /_profiler but without the toolbar, you can cheat:

```
$request->headers->add(array('X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'));
```

That's because in WebProfilerBundle/EventListener/WebDebugToolbarListener.php there's an explicit check for this before injecting the toolbar.

Answer (score -1):

If you are worried about performance - then you should not be running under dev. Dev also limits caching and can pull in additional bundles.

Run in prod mode and warm your cache before you run performance tests.

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted, it's correct, useful information that addresses the question.

Comment: no its not, it doesn't answer OP's question, if the functionality the profiler provides isn't needed, then it does nothing but slow down the development environment

Answer (score -2):

Another way that seems to disable it, is to not have `_dev` in the routing of the application.

So for me in a bitnami install of Symfony 2, simply by changing `app/conf/httpd-app.conf` slightly it would change the program:

```
RewriteBase /symfony/app_dev.php
```

to

```
RewriteBase /symfony/
```

and it would keep the toolbar from coming up.