# Symfony2 default installation keeps on adding a footer to my code

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using the default installation of symfony2. The application is incredibly simple but this thing keeps on adding a footer to responses, it makes 0 sense to me as to why.

base.html.twig:

```
{# app/Resources/views/base.html.twig #}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body>{% block body %}{% endblock %}</body></html>
```

index.html.twig:

```
{# app/Resources/views/index/index.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
STOP TORMENTING ME PLEASE
{%endblock%}
```

DefaultController:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/",name="index")
     */
    public function anAction(Request $request)
    {
    $html = $this->container->get('templating')->render(
        'default/index.html.twig',
        array('username'=>'test','balance'=>50));
       return new Response($html);
    }
}
```

Up until now everything's fun and games.
But then this comes along when I access http://localhost:8000

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    STOP TORMENTING ME 
    <div id="sfwdt240903" class="sf-toolbar" style="display: none"></div><script>/*<![CDATA[*/        Sfjs = (function() {        "use strict";        var classListIsSupported = 'classList' in document.documentElement;        if (classListIsSupported) {            var hasClass = function (el, cssClass) { return el.classList.contains(cssClass); };            var removeClass = function(el, cssClass) { el.classList.remove(cssClass); };            var addClass = function(el, cssClass) { el.classList.add(cssClass); };            var toggleClass = function(el, cssClass) { el.classList.toggle(cssClass); };        } else {            var hasClass = function (el, cssClass) { return el.className.match(new RegExp('\\b' + cssClass + '\\b')); };            var removeClass = function(el, cssClass) { el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + cssClass + '\\b'), ' '); };            var addClass = function(el, cssClass) { if (!hasClass(el, cssClass)) { el.className += " " + cssClass; } };            var toggleClass = function(el, cssClass) { hasClass(el, cssClass) ? removeClass(el, cssClass) : addClass(el, cssClass); };        }        var noop = function() {},            collectionToArray = function (collection) {                var length = collection.length || 0,                    results = new Array(length);                while (length--) {                    results[length] = collection[length];                }                return results;            },            profilerStorageKey = 'sf2/profiler/',            request = function(url, onSuccess, onError, payload, options) {                var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');                options = options || {};                options.maxTries = options.maxTries || 0;                xhr.open(options.method || 'GET', url, true);                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');                xhr.onreadystatechange = function(state) {                    if (4 !== xhr.readyState) {                        return null;                    }                    if (xhr.status == 404 && options.maxTries > 1) {                        setTimeout(function(){                            options.maxTries--;                            request(url, onSuccess, onError, payload, options);                        }, 500);                        return null;                    }                    if (200 === xhr.status) {                        (onSuccess || noop)(xhr);                    } else {                        (onError || noop)(xhr);                    }                };                xhr.send(payload || '');            },            getPreference = function(name) {                if (!window.localStorage) {                    return null;                }                return localStorage.getItem(profilerStorageKey + name);            },            setPreference = function(name, value) {                if (!window.localStorage) {                    return null;                }                localStorage.setItem(profilerStorageKey + name, value);            },            requestStack = [],            renderAjaxRequests = function() {                var requestCounter = document.querySelectorAll('.sf-toolbar-ajax-requests');                if (!requestCounter.length) {                    return;                }                var ajaxToolbarPanel = document.querySelector('.sf-toolbar-block-ajax');                var tbodies = document.querySelectorAll('.sf-toolbar-ajax-request-list');                var state = 'ok';                if (tbodies.length) {                    var tbody = tbodies[0];                    var rows = document.createDocumentFragment();                    if (requestStack.length) {                        for (var i = 0; i < requestStack.length; i++) {                            var request = requestStack[i];                            var row = document.createElement('tr');                            rows.appendChild(row);                            var methodCell = document.createElement('td');                            if (request.error) {                                methodCell.className = 'sf-ajax-request-error';                            }                            methodCell.textContent = request.method;                            row.appendChild(methodCell);                            var pathCell = document.createElement('td');                            pathCell.className = 'sf-ajax-request-url';                            if ('GET' === request.method) {                                var pathLink = document.createElement('a');                                pathLink.setAttribute('href', request.url);                                pathLink.textContent = request.url;                                pathCell.appendChild(pathLink);                            } else {                                pathCell.textContent = request.url;                            }                            pathCell.setAttribute('title', request.url);                            row.appendChild(pathCell);                            var durationCell = document.createElement('td');                            durationCell.className = 'sf-ajax-request-duration';                            if (request.duration) {                                durationCell.textContent = request.duration + "ms";                            } else {                                durationCell.textContent = '-';                            }                            row.appendChild(durationCell);                            row.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));                            var profilerCell = document.createElement('td');                            if (request.profilerUrl) {                                var profilerLink = document.createElement('a');                                profilerLink.setAttribute('href', request.profilerUrl);                                profilerLink.textContent = request.profile;                                profilerCell.appendChild(profilerLink);                            } else {                                profilerCell.textContent = 'n/a';                            }                            row.appendChild(profilerCell);                            var requestState = 'ok';                            if (request.error) {                                requestState = 'error';                                if (state != "loading" && i > requestStack.length - 4) {                                    state = 'error';                                }                            } else if (request.loading) {                                requestState = 'loading';                                state = 'loading';                            }                            row.className = 'sf-ajax-request sf-ajax-request-' + requestState;                        }                        var infoSpan = document.querySelectorAll(".sf-toolbar-ajax-info")[0];                        var children = collectionToArray(tbody.children);                        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {                            tbody.removeChild(children[i]);                        }                        tbody.appendChild(rows);                        if (infoSpan) {                            var text = requestStack.length + ' AJAX request' + (requestStack.length > 1 ? 's' : '');                            infoSpan.textContent = text;                        }                        ajaxToolbarPanel.style.display = 'block';                    } else {                        ajaxToolbarPanel.style.display = 'none';                    }                }                requestCounter[0].textContent = requestStack.length;                var className = 'sf-toolbar-ajax-requests sf-toolbar-value';                requestCounter[0].className = className;                if (state == 'ok') {                    Sfjs.removeClass(ajaxToolbarPanel, 'sf-ajax-request-loading');                    Sfjs.removeClass(ajaxToolbarPanel, 'sf-toolbar-status-red');                } else if (state == 'error') {                    Sfjs.addClass(ajaxToolbarPanel, 'sf-toolbar-status-red');                } else {                    Sfjs.addClass(ajaxToolbarPanel, 'sf-ajax-request-loading');                }            };        var addEventListener;        var el = document.createElement('div');        if (!'addEventListener' in el) {            addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) {                element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, callback);            };        } else {            addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) {                element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);            };        }                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest && XMLHttpRequest.prototype.addEventListener) {                var proxied = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;                XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {                    var self = this;                    /* prevent logging AJAX calls to static and inline files, like templates */                    var path = url;                    if (url.substr(0, 1) === '/') {                        if (0 === url.indexOf('')) {                            path = url.substr(0);                        }                    }                    else if (0 === url.indexOf('http\x3A\x2F\x2F192.168.2.58\x3A8000')) {                        path = url.substr(24);                    }                    if (path.substr(0, 1) === '/' && !path.match(new RegExp("^\/(app(_[\\w]+)?\\.php\/)?_wdt"))) {                        var stackElement = {                            loading: true,                            error: false,                            url: url,                            method: method,                            start: new Date()                        };                        requestStack.push(stackElement);                        this.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {                            if (self.readyState == 4) {                                stackElement.duration = new Date() - stackElement.start;                                stackElement.loading = false;                                stackElement.error = self.status < 200 || self.status >= 400;                                stackElement.profile = self.getResponseHeader("X-Debug-Token");                                stackElement.profilerUrl = self.getResponseHeader("X-Debug-Token-Link");                                Sfjs.renderAjaxRequests();                            }                        }, false);                        Sfjs.renderAjaxRequests();                    }                    proxied.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));                };            }                return {            hasClass: hasClass,            removeClass: removeClass,            addClass: addClass,            toggleClass: toggleClass,            getPreference: getPreference,            setPreference: setPreference,            addEventListener: addEventListener,            request: request,            renderAjaxRequests: renderAjaxRequests,            load: function(selector, url, onSuccess, onError, options) {                var el = document.getElementById(selector);                if (el && el.getAttribute('data-sfurl') !== url) {                    request(                        url,                        function(xhr) {                            el.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;                            el.setAttribute('data-sfurl', url);                            removeClass(el, 'loading');                            (onSuccess || noop)(xhr, el);                        },                        function(xhr) { (onError || noop)(xhr, el); },                        '',                        options                    );                }                return this;            },            toggle: function(selector, elOn, elOff) {                var tmp = elOn.style.display,                    el = document.getElementById(selector);                elOn.style.display = elOff.style.display;                elOff.style.display = tmp;                if (el) {                    el.style.display = 'none' === tmp ? 'none' : 'block';                }                return this;            },            createTabs: function() {                var tabGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.sf-tabs');                /* create the tab navigation for each group of tabs */                for (var i = 0; i < tabGroups.length; i++) {                    var tabs = tabGroups[i].querySelectorAll('.tab');                    var tabNavigation = document.createElement('ul');                    tabNavigation.className = 'tab-navigation';                    for (var j = 0; j < tabs.length; j++) {                        var tabId = 'tab-' + i + '-' + j;                        var tabTitle = tabs[j].querySelector('.tab-title').innerHTML;                        var tabNavigationItem = document.createElement('li');                        tabNavigationItem.setAttribute('data-tab-id', tabId);                        if (j == 0) { Sfjs.addClass(tabNavigationItem, 'active'); }                        if (Sfjs.hasClass(tabs[j], 'disabled')) { Sfjs.addClass(tabNavigationItem, 'disabled'); }                        tabNavigationItem.innerHTML = tabTitle;                        tabNavigation.appendChild(tabNavigationItem);                        var tabContent = tabs[j].querySelector('.tab-content');                        tabContent.parentElement.setAttribute('id', tabId);                    }                    tabGroups[i].insertBefore(tabNavigation, tabGroups[i].firstChild);                }                /* display the active tab and add the 'click' event listeners */                for (i = 0; i < tabGroups.length; i++) {                    tabNavigation = tabGroups[i].querySelectorAll('.tab-navigation li');                    for (j = 0; j < tabNavigation.length; j++) {                        tabId = tabNavigation[j].getAttribute('data-tab-id');                        document.getElementById(tabId).querySelector('.tab-title').className = 'hidden';                        if (Sfjs.hasClass(tabNavigation[j], 'active')) {                            document.getElementById(tabId).className = 'block';                        } else {                            document.getElementById(tabId).className = 'hidden';                        }                        tabNavigation[j].addEventListener('click', function(e) {                            var activeTab = e.target || e.srcElement;                            /* needed because when the tab contains HTML contents, user can click */                            /* on any of those elements instead of their parent '<li>' element */                            while (activeTab.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'li') {                                activeTab = activeTab.parentNode;                            }                            /* get the full list of tabs through the parent of the active tab element */                            var tabNavigation = activeTab.parentNode.children;                            for (var k = 0; k < tabNavigation.length; k++) {                                var tabId = tabNavigation[k].getAttribute('data-tab-id');                                document.getElementById(tabId).className = 'hidden';                                Sfjs.removeClass(tabNavigation[k], 'active');                            }                            Sfjs.addClass(activeTab, 'active');                            var activeTabId = activeTab.getAttribute('data-tab-id');                            document.getElementById(activeTabId).className = 'block';                        });                    }                }            },            createToggles: function() {                var toggles = document.querySelectorAll('.sf-toggle');                for (var i = 0; i < toggles.length; i++) {                    var elementSelector = toggles[i].getAttribute('data-toggle-selector');                    var element = document.querySelector(elementSelector);                    Sfjs.addClass(element, 'sf-toggle-content');                    if (toggles[i].hasAttribute('data-toggle-initial') && toggles[i].getAttribute('data-toggle-initial') == 'display') {                        Sfjs.addClass(element, 'sf-toggle-visible');                    } else {                        Sfjs.addClass(element, 'sf-toggle-hidden');                    }                    Sfjs.addEventListener(toggles[i], 'click', function(e) {                        e.preventDefault();                        var toggle = e.target || e.srcElement;                        /* needed because when the toggle contains HTML contents, user can click */                        /* on any of those elements instead of their parent '.sf-toggle' element */                        while (!Sfjs.hasClass(toggle, 'sf-toggle')) {                            toggle = toggle.parentNode;                        }                        var element = document.querySelector(toggle.getAttribute('data-toggle-selector'));                        Sfjs.toggleClass(element, 'sf-toggle-hidden');                        Sfjs.toggleClass(element, 'sf-toggle-visible');                        /* the toggle doesn't change its contents when clicking on it */                        if (!toggle.hasAttribute('data-toggle-alt-content')) {                            return;                        }                        if (!toggle.hasAttribute('data-toggle-original-content')) {                            toggle.setAttribute('data-toggle-original-content', toggle.innerHTML);                        }                        var currentContent = toggle.innerHTML;                        var originalContent = toggle.getAttribute('data-toggle-original-content');                        var altContent = toggle.getAttribute('data-toggle-alt-content');                        toggle.innerHTML = currentContent !== altContent ? altContent : originalContent;                    });                }            }        };    })();    Sfjs.addEventListener(window, 'load', function() {        Sfjs.createTabs();        Sfjs.createToggles();    });/*]]>*/</script><script>/*<![CDATA[*/    (function () {                Sfjs.load(            'sfwdt240903',            '/_wdt/240903',            function(xhr, el) {                el.style.display = -1 !== xhr.responseText.indexOf('sf-toolbarreset') ? 'block' : 'none';                if (el.style.display == 'none') {                    return;                }                if (Sfjs.getPreference('toolbar/displayState') == 'none') {                    document.getElementById('sfToolbarMainContent-240903').style.display = 'none';                    document.getElementById('sfToolbarClearer-240903').style.display = 'none';                    document.getElementById('sfMiniToolbar-240903').style.display = 'block';                } else {                    document.getElementById('sfToolbarMainContent-240903').style.display = 'block';                    document.getElementById('sfToolbarClearer-240903').style.display = 'block';                    document.getElementById('sfMiniToolbar-240903').style.display = 'none';                }                Sfjs.renderAjaxRequests();                /* Handle toolbar-info position */                var toolbarBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.sf-toolbar-block');                for (var i = 0; i < toolbarBlocks.length; i += 1) {                    toolbarBlocks[i].onmouseover = function () {                        var toolbarInfo = this.querySelectorAll('.sf-toolbar-info')[0];                        var pageWidth = document.body.clientWidth;                        var elementWidth = toolbarInfo.offsetWidth;                        var leftValue = (elementWidth + this.offsetLeft) - pageWidth;                        var rightValue = (elementWidth + (pageWidth - this.offsetLeft)) - pageWidth;                        /* Reset right and left value, useful on window resize */                        toolbarInfo.style.right = '';                        toolbarInfo.style.left = '';                        if (elementWidth > pageWidth) {                            toolbarInfo.style.left = 0;                        }                        else if (leftValue > 0 && rightValue > 0) {                            toolbarInfo.style.right = (rightValue * -1) + 'px';                        } else if (leftValue < 0) {                            toolbarInfo.style.left = 0;                        } else {                            toolbarInfo.style.right = '0px';                        }                    };                }            },            function(xhr) {                if (xhr.status !== 0) {                    confirm('An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (' + xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText + ').\n\nDo you want to open the profiler?') && (window.location = '/_profiler/240903');                }            },            {'maxTries': 5}        );    })();/*]]>*/</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I have no clue where to even begin with trying to remove this footer.

Could anyone please provide me with some help?

Comment: Maybe you should be a farmer, a quiet life without stress.

Comment: Much appreciated mate

Comment: Isn't it just the debug bar you are talking about? This will disappear in the production environment.

Comment: Is there a way to disable it completely?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749939/how-do-i-disable-the-symfony-2-profiler-bar

Comment: Yup... that does the job just right, thanks Peter.

Comment: Lolz - had a good chuckle at this! if your new to symfony i'd suggest you dont bother removing it. Its actually very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can already find in the other answer, the bar is called the debug bar. You will not find this in the twig templates. Instead you can remove it by disabling it in your configuration.

This setting is in `app/config/config_dev.yml`:

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false
```

Answer (score 0):

This footer you are talking about is called the `debug` bar. It helps developers to debug their code while they are in the dev environment. It provides a range of usefull tools like execution time, query manager etc.

You can remove this in different ways:

- switch to prod env to do this just set an htaccess like that in your web folder :

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
  ```
- or you can remove the symfony web profiler bundle from your kernel :

  // Comment this line to disable
  $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();

Comment: A third and best option is to just disable it in the `config_dev.yml` file